# aws-sdk S3: list all keys with listObjectsV2 in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, state, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a list of all files within a specific bucket and render that on the UI, I'm able to get the information logged to the console which is currently an array of 8 objects, with "Key" being the name property of each file like so:

[image]

The problem I'm having is that when I try to set these "Key" properties to my state to be able to map through and display them in a list, I end up with the data running in a continuous loop in the console and I'm not sure why. This is what I have so far in my file:

[image]

If I try to "setListFiles" to the "contents" below the console log, this is where the continuous loop starts happening. Forgive me if it's something simple that I'm doing wrong as this is still new to me but I would really appreciate any guidance, thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post your code, not the image so people can copy/paste your code somewhere to debug it.

Comment: Could you post the code where your call listFiles?

Comment: You're right, noted for next time thank you

Comment: I haven't called it yet, I'm trying to put the contents into my "setListFiles" state array which I created at the top but when I do so, that's when the console.log(contents) enters an almost infinite loop and breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop I mentioned was due to not calling s3.listObjects within a useEffect, so "setListFiles" was called, the component re-rendered and s3.listObjects was called again with the cycle then repeating hence why I got the infinite loop. My final code for this file is like so:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const params = {
  Bucket: 'elixivity-libra-lu001-companyrawdata-dev',
  Delimiter: '',
  Prefix: 'samplecompany/',
};

const BucketList = () => {
  const [listFiles, setListFiles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        setListFiles(data.Contents);
        console.log(data.Contents);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <div className='card-header'>SampleCompany Files</div>
      <ul className='list-group'>
        {listFiles &&
          listFiles.map((name, index) => (
            <li className='list-group-item' key={index}>
              {name.Key}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BucketList;
```